# Posting to google analytics from Delphi app

Tags: delphi, google-analytics

I've been tasked with sending data from a Delphi 2010 desktop app to google analytics so we can track which parts of the program are being used more heavily (or used at all). I'm using Indy to post, and the post seems to be generating a valid response, but I'm not seeing anything on the Google Analytics side. I'm totally new to Google Analytics, so might be doing something wrong with what I'm posting or in how I am viewing it. I did create an app view in analytics, but don't know if I set it up correctly.

```
Parameters := TStringList.Create;
Parameters.Add('v=1'); //Version
Parameters.Add('&tid=UA-nnnnnnnn-n'); //Tracking ID
Parameters.Add('&cid=555');           //
Parameters.Add('&t=test2');           // Screenview hit type.
Parameters.Add('&an=AppName');        // App name
Parameters.Add('&av=' + sAppVersion);   // App version
Parameters.Add('&aid=12345');           // App Id
Parameters.Add('&aiid=InstallerID');    // App Installer Id
IdHTTP.Post('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect',Parameters);
Result:= IdHTTP.ResponseText;
```

I've verified that the tracking ID (replaced with UA-nnnnnnnn-n above) is correct. Would like to know if what I'm submitting is complete and/or if there's something I need to do to see the hit on the GA side. Thanks.

Comment: You may already be aware of this but GA has some latency before events show up unless you are looking at the real-time views. And the default filtering excludes everything for today, unless you save your filters to behave differently. If you're new to GA, you may be expecting results to show up in GA while you are testing your app, but that's not the default behavior.

Comment: I did pick up on this. I both watched the real-time views, and I went back to look for events from a few days ago. Someone else set up GA so I'm not sure the problem isn't there--but the filters appear to be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one. Turned out to be three things that needed help:

1. When manually constructing https parameters, one generally needs an & before each new parameter. When passing parameters in a TStringList with Indy's TIdHTTP.Post, an & before parameters doesn't generate any error that returns, but it also doesn't work. Taking the & out of the parameters.Add fixes this.
2. To figure out which parameters must be included together, the analytics hit builder provides a way to quickly determine whether a hit is valid or whether there's a missing parameter. (Some parameters are required only in combination.)
   (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)
3. An incoming hit (even in valid format from the hit builder) can result in no visible results without building a dashboard/widgit or report specifically designed to show the type of hit you are generating. Thus, an existing site that has been configured to count web page views doesn't seem to show app hits or events or types of hits that are different than the existing views are configured for.

Fix them all, and things work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `/debug/collect/` endpoint instead of `/collect/`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) to validate your hits and receive a response containing any possible errors for each request.

Comment: I switched to `'.../debug/collect'` but get only "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" in the ResponseText (same as I got before adding /debug). If I end with `'.../debug/collect/'` (with the / at the end), I get Error: EIdHTTPProtocolException: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found (which errors out before I get to the response text).